# LINQ to see if all items in an object's List property are included in the current selection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Key` object that has an attribute of type `List<int>` and it is called `KeyProperties`. `Key` object also has an int `Id` attribute.

```
class Key
{
   public int Id;
   public List<int> KeyProperties;
}
```

I have a list of integers called `currentSelection`.

I would like to prevent the user from creating a `Key` that has the exact same integers as in `currentSelection`. That means if `currentSelection` is:

```
List<int> = new List<int>() {7,8,10};
```

I do not want the user to create a `Key` with a `KeyProperties` attribute of (7,8,10). But still the user will be able to create `Key`s with (7,8) or (7,8,15).

How can I achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: What about `{10, 8, 7}`?  What about `{7, 8, 9, 10}`?

Comment: Actually, `Key` is a *class*, and `Keyproperties` is a *property* (not an object and attribute).

Comment: Look at `SequenceEqual`

Comment: a) Are the ints ensured in the Key ordered?
b) Where and when do you want to do this _validation_? 
c) When the validation occurs how can the currentSelection is accessible? Is it a parameter or member variable or local variable?

Comment: @JonathanWood true, but I didn't want the reader to be confused when I say there is a property called `KeyProperties`.

Comment: @g.pickardou order is not important.

Comment: @Pedram meaning if an existing entry had `{7, 8, 9, 10}` then the user would not be able to add `{7, 8, 9}`?

Comment: @DStanley `{7, 8, 9, 10}` is allowed. We just don't want to have an exact match and order is not important.

Comment: @Pedram so your comment "both accepted" is wrong for `{10, 8, 7}`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yes. sorry `{10, 8, 7}` should not be allowed.

Comment: @DStanley sorry `{10, 8, 7}` should not be allowed.

Comment: by the way, what about `{7, 7, 8, 10}` Is it possible ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus that is not going to happen in the program since the integers are primary key ids.

Comment: So you may just do `list1.Except(list2).Any()` => if it's true, you can add the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
//currentSelection.Sort();
//theKey.KeyProperties.Sort();
bool valid = !currentSelection.SequenceEqual(theKey.KeyProperties)
```

I recommend to switch to a `` ISet`1 `` implementation like `` HashSet`1 `` though to skip the sorting process *if the order is irrelevant*.

Comment: This isn't a requirement?

Comment: Still works, just add in `.Sort()` to the selection and KeyProperties

Answer (score 1):

Use [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<int> currSelection = new List<int>() {7,8,10};

public bool CanCreateKey(List<int> keyToCheck)
{
   return !currSelection.All(i => keyToCheck.Contains(i));
}
```

Comment: This may be wrong if both  `{7, 7, 8, 10}` and `{7, 8, 10}` are accepted

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I also will have problems if keyToCheck == null or if I'm out of memory :)

Comment: This is not the  same problem. You just don't manage duplicates, if they are allowed, than you give wrong result.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - That's correct for the sequenceequals answers as well if they are allowed.

Comment: If duplicates are allowed -> SequenceEqual and my way is false.
Otherwise -> my way is true and SequenceEqual is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool valid = !currentSelection.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(theKey.KeyProperties.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Comment: Doesn't compile; either sort separatedly or use `OrderBy`

Comment: Oops, getting my sorting methods mixed up! Thanks.